# How to check if given font family is a Composite font?

Tags: wpf, fonts

We can enumerate over the fonts available on system using Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.

1. How can I distinguish between composite fonts and plain-font?
2. How can I get the FontFamilies used in a composite font?

I tried FontFamily.FamilyTypefaces, but it wasn't helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking [FontFamily.FamilyMaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.familymaps.aspx), which should always be empty for physical fonts and non-empty for composite fonts.

```
var font1 = new FontFamily("Global User Interface");
var isComposite1 = font1.FamilyMaps.Any(); // True
var font2 = new FontFamily("Arial");
var isComposite2 = font2.FamilyMaps.Any(); // False
```

Comment: Thanks Quartermeister, Its fine for me to move to .NET 4.0.